# How to hold a seleted dropdown entity type value in JQuery variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring-boot, thymeleaf

> I am using STS 3.9.0 Tool, my project based on Spring Boot, Thymeleaf,
>   Mysql, Html-Bootstrap and JQuery.

I am showing a dropdown component as apartment list which is taken from thymeleaf,which holds entity values, so I am showing apartment name, But passing entity of particular(selected) apartment only.
But I am posting the data using JQUERY via Ajax call..

I have done the code like below
**HTML code..**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="societyname">Society Name</label> 
    <select id="societyname" class="form-control">
        <option th:each="propertydetails:${propertydetails}" th:value="${propertydetails}" th:text="${propertydetails.propertyname}">        
        </option>
    </select>
</div>
```

**Jquery**

```
var formData = {
    entPropertyMaster : $("#societyname").val(),
}

alert(JSON.stringify(formData));

// DO POST
$.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    contentType : "application/json",
    url : url+"/saveflat",
    data :JSON.stringify(formData),
    dataType : 'json',
    success : function(result) {
        if(result.status == "saved") {
            $("#resultid").html("<strong>" +result.dataObj.flatname+ " Registered Successfully!" );
        } else {
            $("#resultid").html("<strong>Error</strong>");
        }

        alert(result.status);
        console.log(result);
    },
    error : function(e) {
        alert("Error!");
        alert(url);
        console.log("ERROR: ", e);
    }
});
```

**@controller**

```
//To save the flat registration details
@PostMapping("/saveflat")
public ResponseMsg doSaveFlatDetails(@ModelAttribute EntFlatMaster flatDetails) {
    ResponseMsg responsemsg = new ResponseMsg();
    EntFlatMaster flatMaster = new EntFlatMaster();
    try {
        String logResponse = null;
        /*for Master*/
        if(flatDetails!=null) {
            flatMaster = serflatDetails.doSaveFlatDetails(flatDetails);
            /*for Log*/
            if(flatMaster!=null) {
                logResponse = doSaveLogFlatDetails(flatDetails,flatMaster.getPkflatid());
            }

            /*for response message to web for master and Log both are saved checking process*/
            if(logResponse.equals("saved")) {
                responsemsg = new ResponseMsg("saved",flatMaster);
            } else {
                responsemsg = new ResponseMsg("failed",flatMaster);
            }
        }   
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        e.printStackTrace();
        responsemsg = new ResponseMsg("failed",flatMaster);
    }
    return responsemsg;
}
```

**@Entity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="flatdetails")
public class EntFlatMaster implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7066060644146063944L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="pkflatid")
    private int pkflatid;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="fkpropertymasterid")
    private EntPropertyMaster entPropertyMaster = new EntPropertyMaster();
}
```

Please Help to solve this...Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Can you please be more specific with errors you are facing? Stacktrace and so on?

Firstly your Thymeleaf code is wrong, use the below:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="societyname">Society Name</label> 
    <select id="societyname" class="form-control">
        <option th:each="pd :${propertydetails}" th:value="${pd.id}" 
            th:text="${pd.propertyname}"></option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Look at the `th:value="${pd.id}"` this will hold the identifier for your property.

While building the form data you need to use `pkflatid` and not `entPropertyMaster`

Comment: when i passing PKid means that holds the particular entity value?

Comment: @VigneshR I am unable to understand what you have said

Comment: First @MohamedSanaulla Thanks for reply...@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name="fkpropertymasterid")
private EntPropertyMaster entPropertyMaster = new EntPropertyMaster(); --- this is my entity, so here i mentioned EntPropertyMaster  type of variable,so as u said in your code "th:value="${pd.id}"",which means it holds integer value only right?so my question is "as per your code it will pass as a Entity type in my JQUERY variable?"

Comment: With `pd.id` I meant that you need to use any of the identifier of your property. Just like you have `propertyName`, there should be an identifier for property. You haven't provided the property model information, so I just generalized it to `id`

Comment: It is little bit length to show,so thats why i give my doubted (particular problem) portion of the code...please tell me that JQUERY will holds the entity (Entire Row data) or particular column value only (pkid)?

Comment: from jquery/ui you just need to pass the identifier and then you can get the identifier details on the server.

Comment: I got JSON Parse Error like ".w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Failed to read HTTP message:org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot construct instance of `com.vfraternity.entity.EntPropertyMaster` (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('1');nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot construct instance of `com.vfraternity.entity.EntPropertyMaster` (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument

Comment: Please help me guys...ERROR -- no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('1') ..This is the same error which i previously commented...